# Why does my Xcode project compile only when it's in a workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-project

I have an Xcode project **P2** which is part of a workspace where I have another project **P1**.

When I build **P1**, it creates a Cocoa Touch Framework. In **P2**, I have added the framework created by P1 by going to 
**General-->Link Frameworks and Libraries-->Select P1.framework.**

Then I build the **P2** project and it compiles successfully with the **P1.framework** integrated in it. So, all good with this.

Now instead of opening the workspace and building the **P2** project from workspace, I directly open the **P2** project by clicking `p2.xcodeproj` file. I can see the `p1.framework` file in it.

But, now when I try to build **P2**, it gives error:

> framework not found P1. clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Can anyone help me to understand why **P2** gives error when directly opened from `p2.xcodeproj` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `p1.framework` to be linkable **properly**, the project where `p1.framework` is referenced from *must* be  visible.

This is probably because you initially used the standard Xcode UI to choose the `p1.framework` from the `P1` project in your workspace. Xcode doesn't directly reference `p1.framework`, but rather *via* the `P1` project. This is useful, because it allows you to modify `P1` as much as you like (changing the build destinations, etc.) and yet allows other projects to use the `p1.framework`.

An easier analogy might be to think of folder aliases. It's like you reference a file via a folder alias, and then you delete that folder. Naturally, errors appear.